# PHPExcel not computing the sum of cells

Tags: php, sum, phpexcel

I have the following piece of code for computing the sum of cells in a PHPExcel generated Excel document:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(21, $j+2, '=SUM(K'.$s.':U'.$s.')');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(22, $j+2, '=IF(V'.$s.'>= 10, "1", "0")');
```

When I open the Excel document, the column which has to display the sum of previous cells has a 0 value and the `SUM()` formula is not present in the formula bar.

Comment: @Portland Runner - I don't recall a writeFormula() method in the PHPExcel library, do you know something that I don't? Or are you thinking of a different library?

Comment: Without a bit more information, it's difficult to say: what Writer are you using? If you do a getValue() or a getCalculatedValue() immediately after setting the cell value, what do you get?